# Sort and remove duplicates in place and recursively

Tags: debian, sort, recursive, text, uniq

I would like to sort all files in all subdirectories in place. I have 65536 files in 256 directories, every file containing one word a line, and each file contains duplicates.

What I would like is to sort these with -u option (I don't know why but if I pipe sort to uniq -u command it actually removes unique lines that were duplicates, which is weird but anyway), but I don't want any ouput file, I want sort to read the files in memory, then overwrite them. I tried the -o option but it needs a filename.

Is there a way to perform this recursively ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

That can be just:

```
find . -type f -size +1c -exec sort -uo {} {} ';'
```

(here skipping the files that are less than 2 byte large as you need at least 3 bytes to make two different lines, or possibly 2 for `"\nx"` which is an empty line followed by an undelimited line¹).

Beware the default sort order in `sort` is based on the locale's collation algorithm.

Two lines can sort the same even if they're not byte-to-byte identical, especially if the lines contain sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters, and also on GNU systems such as Debian on characters whose collation order is not defined.

You can do:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -type f -exec sort -uo {} {} ';'
```

Instead which on ASCII based systems (such as Debian on all architectures and kernels it's available for) will sort the lines by byte value instead of locale collation order (or IOW, the collation order of the C locale is based on byte value) and should guarantee that two byte-to-byte-different lines don't sort the same.

That runs one invocation of `sort` per file. To speed things up if the files are reasonably short, you could instead do with `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
for f (**/*(N.)) print -rC1 -v 'mapfile[$f]' - ${(fou)mapfile[$file]}
```

Which avoids running an external `sort` command so many times and uses its `o` and `u` parameter expansion flag to sort and unique the lines instead. Note that it strips empty lines in the input if any, and skips hidden files (add the `D` glob qualifier if you want them).

Contrary to GNU `sort -u`, `zsh` won't consider as duplicate two strings that are not byte-to-byte identical (even if they sort the same), so you don't need to fix the locale to C there.

```
$ locale title charmap
English locale for Britain
UTF-8
$ a=( )
$ print -rC1 - $a | sort -u
  (oops, the vampire vanished as it sorted the same as the fairy)
$ print -rC1 - ${(ou)a}
```

As to your question about `uniq -u`, that's what it's for, `uniq -u` reports lines that are unique in the input. To remove duplicates, it's just `sort | uniq`. The complement of `uniq -u` would be `uniq -D` (report all duplicated lines).

GNU `uniq` used to report the first of sequences of lines that sort the same (so `sort -u` would be the same as `sort | uniq`). Newer versions report the first of sequences of identical lines, so `sort | uniq` cannot be used anymore if there can be different lines that sort the same.

Here, with newer GNU versions:

```
$ print -rC1      | sort | uniq
```

Since fairies and vampires sort the same in my locale, the `sort` result will be left as in the input (as GNU `sort` uses a stable sort algorithm), and `uniq` will only remove duplicates if the input happened to original contain adjacent duplicates.

What we can do though is first `sort` by byte value, and then by collation order before calling `uniq`:

```
LC_ALL=C sort | sort | LC_ALL=C uniq
```

Calling `uniq` under `LC_ALL=C` will make older and newer versions work the same.

---

<sup>`sort` does add back that newline character if it was missing in the input, in effect making a text file out of that non-text file. By skipping the 1-byte size files that contain non-newline bytes, that means those files are not fixed, so you may want to skip that optimisation if you still want the benefit of that text-file fixing, or extend the optimisation to `-size +2c` if you know all your files are properly formed text files.</sup>

Comment: Why `LC_ALL=C` instead of just `LC_COLLATE=C`, since it's only the collating which is always causing problems? This makes no difference here (no `-f`, `-i` or `-n` options relying on `LC_CTYPE`), but it still feels like overkill.

Comment: @UncleBilly, because (1) `LC_COLLATE` doesn't take precedence over `LC_ALL` so you can't be sure `LC_COLLATE=C` will have any effect regardless of the environment it's called in. Doing `LC_ALL= LC_COLLATE=C` would make sure `LC_COLLATE` is taken into account, but then, that's potentially radically changing the localisation settings anyway and also (2) I've seen systems where having `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` not agree causes problems. `LC_ALL=C` is like disabling localisation which most of the time is what we want.

Comment: I fail to see what's wrong with `LC_ALL= LC_COLLATE=C` (other than guard against the abuse of `LC_ALL` perpetuated by such examples as `LC_ALL=C` ;-). As to `LC_COLLATE=C` and `LC_CTYPE=something_else` conflicting, that's certainly interesting.

Comment: @UncleBilly, in any case `printf '\200\n\201\n' | LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL= LC_COLLATE=C sort -u` would just fail with `sort: Illegal byte sequence` with some implementation. If the point  is to remove byte-to-byte identical lines, there's no need to decode the input as characters. While you could also add `LC_CTYPE=C`, that would mean you'd also likely need to change `LC_MESSAGES` as otherwise `sort`'s error messages could no longer be displayed in the user's language anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find . -type f -exec perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -i -0 -n -e \
    'print join("\n", uniq split /\n/), "\n"' {} +
```

This uses `find` to pass the filenames to a `perl` script which uses the `-i` edit-in-place option, and the [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/release/List-MoreUtils) to provide a `uniq` function to perl (perl has `sort` built-in, but not `uniq`).  perl's `-n` option does pretty much the same thing as `sed`'s `-n` option - it iterates over each input record, but prints nothing by default (i.e. it only prints what is explicitly printed).

The script sets the input record separator to NUL (with the `-0` option) so it can slurp in each file in one go.  Then it splits each input file by newlines, and prints them out in unique sorted order.

`List::MoreUtils` is in the `liblist-moreutils-perl` package on Debian (and Ubuntu, Mint, etc), and probably has a similar package name on Fedora, Centos, and maybe RHEL. Other distros probably have it packaged too.  Otherwise install it from CPAN.

If you don't want to (or can't) install `List::MoreUtils`, you can use an associative array (aka "hash") instead.  e.g.

```
$ find . -type f -exec perl -i -0 -n -e \
    '%uniq = map {$_ => 1} split /\n/;
     print join("\n", sort keys %uniq), "\n"' {} +
```

I'd run either of these on some junk files first, to make sure that it does what you want. And/or test it without the `-i` option so it just prints to stdout.  I tested it on a file called `junk` that had the contents:

```
6
5
5
4
3
2
1
1
```

after running either of the versions above, `junk` contained:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

If you want them in reverse sorted order, you can add `reverse` before either the `sort` or `uniq` function.  e.g. `print join("\n", reverse sort keys %uniq),"\n"`.

---

Alternatively, if you have [sponge](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) from Joey Hess's `moreutils` installed, you can use `find`, `shell`, `sort -u`, and `sponge`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c \
  'for f in "$@"; do sort -u "$f" | sponge "$f" ; done' find-sh {} +
```

This will be significantly slower than the perl version because the `sh` has to fork `sort` and `sponge` once **for each** input file, instead of `perl` being forked just once(*) by `find` to process all of the input files.

(*) assuming all the filenames fit into one command line. On Linux, that's about 2 million characters worth.  If all the filenames combined are longer than that, it might have to fork perl two or three times (or maybe more).

The same applies to `sh` being forked by `find`, it might need to be forked more than once - but the cost of forking sh (or perl) a few times is negligible compared to the cost of forking `sort` and `sponge` **once for each file**.   The time saving comes from using `+` with `find ... -exec ... {}` instead of `\;`.

Comment: Hi and thank you for these answers, very complete. I'm running the first version with sort -uo and it is working perfectly, quite fast too. Thank you both for your answers !

Comment: Note that to slurp, you'd typically use `-0777`. `-0` splits on NULs

Comment: since the files are **text** files (and can't contain NULs), `-0` works too, just as well as `-0777`.

Comment: Note that for files that end in empty lines and don't contain empty lines other than at the end, that will remove all of them.

Comment: Note that you don't need `sponge` for `sort` if you use `sort -o`. As, for obvious reasons, `sort` needs to read its input whole before it can start writing its output, so it is able to write to the same file as it's getting input from.

Comment: Since trashing the input file by trying to use it as the output is such a common problem, it's better to just use `sponge` than to remember a list of programs which don't need it (a very small list), or have to deduce it from principles like "sort reads all of it's input before doing anything".   sponge will work in all cases, no need to remember or deduce anything, as will the `-i` option of perl, sed, and others.    Also, `{} {}` is just plain ugly, aesthetically very unpleasing.   Any further irrelevant nitpicks?

Comment: BTW,  the fact that GNU sort doesn't open its output file until it has finished reading and sorting all of the input may not be true for some versions of sort.   There's no reason an implementation of sort can't or won't open it's output file handle as soon as it sees the `-o` option.

Comment: That has been the behaviour of `sort` since the first version of `sort` in the 70s and is specified by POSIX, so can be relied upon.

Comment: `sort file | sponge file` will clobber the file if `sort`  fails for some reason (like the file is write-only). `sort -o file file` won't. `sponge` stores the whole file in memory, `sort` resorts to temp files as needed. `sort` is a standard command, `sponge` is not. There are not only advantages to using `sponge`.

Comment: Good for you. How about you focus on your own answers instead of nitpicking mine at every opportunity?  It seems i can't post an answer without you coming up with some trivial crap to criticise it, or making some overly pedantic, irrelevant, and unnecessary edit (which you've promised before to stop doing, but haven't).  My perl answer works.  My sponge answer works.  It doesn't matter at all that sponge isn't strictly necessary for `sort -o`, it (or a temp file) **is** necessary for almost all other programs when you're trying to write to the same file that you're reading from.

Comment: I'm sorry that you're viewing those comments as aggressions, it is not my intention to criticise you personally. My objective here is to try and improve the quality of answers on this site.  When I can, I try and list the limitations of my own answers, so users can make an educated decision whether they're acceptable for their use case. If you do spot any problem in my answers, please do report them, that will be much appreciated.

Comment: I see them your comments as nitpicking and bullying.  And your edits to my posts are rarely, if ever, helpful or useful and often change the meaning of my post or "put words in my mouth" that i had no intention of uttering myself.  I already revert your edits immediately most of the time and from now on will automatically revert your edits to my posts without looking at them.